# How I insert a same data in multiple controllers ($scope) with one call in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, controller, factory

I am using a factory to be call in two controllers that are in same page, however I don't want that this call AJAX two times. I'm try use `$q.defer()`, but it doesn't work!

The code:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('globalApp', []).config([
        '$interpolateProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function ($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
        }
    ]);

    // Index Store List
    app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$storeList',
        function ($scope, $storeList) {
            $scope.stores = [];
            $storeList.getStoreList().then(function (stores) {
                $scope.stores = stores;
            });
        }]);

    // Footer Store List
    app.controller('StoreListController', [
        '$scope', '$storeList',
        function ($scope, $storeList) {
            $scope.stores = [];
            $storeList.getStoreList().then(function (stores) {
                $scope.stores = stores;
            });
        }
    ]);
    
    // Factory call list os stores
    app.factory('$storeList', function ($http, $q) {
        var stores = [];
        return {
            getStoreList: function () {
                //is a request needed?
                if (stores.length > 0) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(stores);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
                var uri = rootUrl + 'getStoreList';
                var responsePromise = $http.get(uri);
                return responsePromise.then(function (result) {
                    var data = result.data;
                    //modify collection of stores...
                    if (data.status) {
                        var stores = data.stores;
                        return stores;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

```html
<body ng-app="globalApp">

  <section> 
    <div ng-controller="IndexController">
       <nav>
        <a ng-repeat="store in stores" href="<%store.link%>"><%store.name%></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <div>
        <ul ng-controller="StoreListController">
            <li ng-repeat="store in stores">
                <h3><a href="<%store.link%>"><%store.name%></a></h3>
                <p>
                    <%store.street%>, <%store.number%>
                    <%store.neighborhood%>, <%store.cityName%>
                    <a><%store.phone%></a>
                    <a><%store.email%></a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // My configs (optional)
    var app = angular.module('globalApp', []).config([
        '$interpolateProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function ($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
        }
    ]);

    // Index Store List
    app.controller('IndexController', [
        '$scope', '$storeList', 'StoreService',
        function ($scope, $storeList, StoreService) {
            $scope.stores = [];
            $storeList.getStoreList().then(function (stores) {
                $scope.stores = stores;
                StoreService.setStores(stores);
            });

        }]);
  
    // Footer Store List
    app.controller('StoreListController', [
        '$scope', 'StoreService',
        function ($scope, StoreService) {
            $scope.stores = [];
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return StoreService.getStores();
            }, function (stores) {
                $scope.stores = stores;
            }, true);

        }
    ]);
  
    // StoreService to share vars between the controllers
    app.service('StoreService', function () {
        var stores = [];
        return {
            setStores: function (_stores) {
                stores = _stores;
            },
            getStores: function () {
                return stores;
            }
        };
    });
  
    // Factory make ajax call to get list of stores
    app.factory('$storeList', function ($http) {
        return {
            getStoreList: function () {
                var uri = rootUrl + 'getStoreList';
                var responsePromise = $http.get(uri);
                return responsePromise.then(function (result) {
                    var data = result.data;
                    if (data.status) {
                        return data.stores;
                    }
                    return [];
                });
            }
        };
    });
  
}());
```

```html
<body ng-app="globalApp">

  <section> 
    <div ng-controller="IndexController">
       <nav>
        <a ng-repeat="store in stores" href="<%store.link%>"><%store.name%></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <div>
        <ul ng-controller="StoreListController">
            <li ng-repeat="store in stores">
                <h3><a href="<%store.link%>"><%store.name%></a></h3>
                <p>
                    <%store.street%>, <%store.number%>
                    <%store.neighborhood%>, <%store.cityName%>
                    <a><%store.phone%></a>
                    <a><%store.email%></a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If both controllers load at the same time and call the function, stores will not contain any data so it's length will evaluate to 0.

If you need to do this onLoad of the page why don't you call the function from a service and store the results. You can utilize an **observer pattern** in the controls to listen for changes to the set and persist those changes to both controllers to set the value of $scope.stores once the promise resolves.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 'services' to share the data between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have defer here. Remove this chunk:

```
          //is a request needed?
            if (stores.length > 0) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(stores);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

And your `IndexController` and `StoreListController` are both loading the storelist and hence 2 AJAX calls. Remove the chunk from either of the 2 controllers

```
        $scope.stores = [];
        $storeList.getStoreList().then(function (stores) {
            $scope.stores = stores;
        });
```

**EDIT**

I Did not realize earlier, but since you are using the storeList outside the scope of your StoreController, You should remove the `.getStoreList()` call from StoreController only

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 'services' to share the data between controllers.